# Enhanced Domain

Tags: mobilesdk, enhanced-domains

We use the Mobile SDK to create iOS and Android applications.

After this week's update to Winter '23 and enabling the Enhanced Domain setting for production, users can't use our apps. When the users log into our app (with a community user), they get a 403 error, but we can't see any debug logs of the attempts. After reinstalling the apps, it starts to work.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to get any direction to fix it.
we have community users that can't login to our app from the time the enhanced domain was enabled on our env.
all the users get 403 error.
and it solved after reinstalling